# Unable to get basic info using facebook sdk 3.0 in my android application

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to access the facebook user's basic information using `facebook session login`. however I am not able to access their basic information.
 I am getting facebook error message `An error occured. Please try again later.`

Following is my code to access facebook using session login,

```
private void onClickLogin() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info")).setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }
```

Please any one help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried, getting started with Facebook SDk link. it worked perfectly for me

Comment: yes, I have tried. But still didn't work for me.

Comment: try to log out exception field in statusCallback class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the permission on the login button:

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info"));
```